# iphone; UITabBarController inside a view, chopped tab icons?

Tags: iphone, icons, uitabbarcontroller

Hi there
am not sure if i am doing this right.
I am loading a view with a tab bar controller inside from another view.
Main View - a simple button, on click opens sub view with a tab bar controller and some tabs
Sub View - on load, loading the tab bar controller(tabs) into a view(tabview) and tehn displaying it using

```
[tabview addSubview:tabs.view];
```

The above mentioned works, except that the tab icons seem to be cropped at the bottom. i have not changed any default view settings.

My question is, is the method that i am using right?
How to avoid the icons being chopped at the bottom?

Since i cant uplaod images, i am giving the url of the simulator screen
http://www.picpaste.com/iPhoneTabBarProblem-EnSNHJTo.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks but i guess i found the answer
i was totally wrong in adding a tabbar controller to a view, it is supposed to be added to a window. Once i did that it was fine.

Thanks again